# Identity Server 4 / .Net Core 2.0 : Database persistent users

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

How do I use database entities rather than using this line of code:

```
    services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetTestUsers());
```

I am using.Net Core 2.0 and the latest release of Identity Server 4.
Background of the project: I wanted to create a separate auth server that will allow access to web API endpoints using roles or claims - on tokens.

Comment: You could start by reading the docs...

Comment: I am currently using the above setup on AuthServer i made. I would want to get token using username and password, using 'TestUsers' i am able to create and return an access token however, when i try to get a [AspNet]User persisting in the DB, i cannot get a token.

Here is the code

var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(user.UserName, login.Password, "api");

This code is in the 'resource api' project.

Comment: Please read this recently updated article: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4